# Django Elastic Beanstalk Deploy showing 404

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm attempting to deploy my first Django app to Elastic Beanstalk. The Beanstalk created successfully via command line tools, I uploaded from my Mercurial via ZIP, that seemed to work just fine. But I'm getting a 404 when attempting to access it.

Elastic Beanstalk HTTP Error (the log is huge, I can parse more, but I only see this for an error)

`[Fri Jan 03 18:08:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py`

WSGI Settings for the Django app

wsgi.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "company.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

settings.py

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'company.wsgi.application'
```

This works fine locally and I'm sure I'm just not understanding something that I should be.

Please help!

Folder structure:

```
 /opt/python/current/app/

  - company
     - static
     - templates
     - wsgi.py
     - settings.py
     - __init__.py
     - urls.py

  - webapp
     - templates
  - manage.py
  - requirements.txt
```

Comment: Can you show us the hierarchy of your project (folders, ...). It seems the WSGI script is not at the path you give in your setting...

Comment: Added above, I didn't include all of the files, but those should be the ones needed to see

Comment: Also to see if it was a configuration issue with my command line, I redeployed via console and received the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the absolute path of your project :-) In this case, what's `/opt/python/current/app/application.py`?

Comment: In the EC2 server /opt/python/current/app/[EC2ApplicationName] is there as a folder, but no application.py file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS Elastic Beanstalk's default configuration sets `WSGIPath` to `application.py`, you either need to rename your file with mappings to application.py or configure the environment to point to your mappings script.

Detailed information can be found in AWS Elastic Beanstalk Python Container Options: [Option Values](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#command-options-python)

You can set it with the management console

[image]

Or with `.ebextensions` [option_settings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-options)

**NB:** It should be relative path.

Comment: The .ebextensions option_settings got me past the 404, now I'm getting a 500 :(

Comment: ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: Add DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to .ebextensions, it is blank by default.

Comment: It's already there as `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "company.settings"`

Comment: Can you post configuration file from .ebextensions? It should look like option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "company.settings"

Comment: Sure, here you go : `option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "company.settings"
    "application_stage": "staging"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: company/wsgi.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"`

Comment: Changing the setting manually through EB fixed it, I'm not sure why it was needed when it was specifically set in the option_settings file. Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction, now I just have to figure out Postgres on EB (which I'll start another thread for).

Comment: You welcome. I'm glad it worked out for you. I'm not sure either why option_settings did not work, have a look here if you want to follow-up: [Step 6: Update Application](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html)

Comment: In the EB management console, after clicking the gear to edit the Software Configuration, there was no WSGIPATH to edit, added it under Static Files and it worked: not so intuitive.